# Dúvida sobre como gerar números aleatórios

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um exercício em java. Consegui fazer gerar 6 números aleatórios, agora, as vezes o número está dando repetido. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
public class MegaSenna {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random radom = new Random();
        gerandoNumeroSorteio(radom);
    }

    private static void gerandoNumeroSorteio(Random radom) {
        int numeroTmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            numeroTmp = radom.nextInt(60 + 1);
            System.out.println((i+1)+"º numero sorteado = " + numeroTmp);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Você está pedindo um número aleatória com limite superior de `60+1`, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Adicione em um array o número aleatório, porém antes de adicionar o número no array verifique se no array já não consta esse número, depois exiba o conteúdo final do array

Answer (score 1):

No Java 8 existe o método [`ints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) para gerar um array de números inteiros:

```
// Gera um array contendo 6 números de entre 1 e 60.
int []valores = new Random().ints(6, 1, 60).toArray();
```

#### [Funcionando no IDEONE.](https://ideone.com/Bk7MEr)

Answer (score 0):

Crie um array pra esses número e faça o método `gerandoNumeroSorteio` retornar esse array.

O método foi modificado pra criar um array e ser populado sempre testando(com o método `contemNumeroNoArray` se esse número gerado já existe no array.

o método `contemNumeroNoArray` recebe um `número` e um `array` e verifica se esse número existe no `array` passado.

```
public class MegaSenna {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random radom = new Random();
        int[] randomNumbers = gerandoNumeroSorteio(radom);

        for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + "º numero sorteado = " + randomNumbers[i]);
        }

    }

    private static int[] gerandoNumeroSorteio(Random radom) {
        int numbers[] = new int[6];
        int numeroTmp;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 6) {
            numeroTmp = radom.nextInt(60 + 1);
            if (!contemNumeroNoArray(numeroTmp, numbers)) {
                numbers[i] = numeroTmp;
                i++;
            }
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    private static boolean contemNumeroNoArray(int numeroTmp, int[] numbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] == numeroTmp)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu tinha feito muito parecido com essa forma, o meu professor pediu que eu não usa-se Collection.

Comment: Pronto @daysonrodrigues, se você não pode usar ArrayList, está ai com array normal.

Comment: valeu fera, me ajudou demais obrigado!

Comment: @daysonrodrigues se minha resposta resolveu seu problema. aceita ela como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa mais simples. 
Você pode gerar um número aleatório a partir de um tempo do sistema (System.nanoTime())...
Verifica se é repetido e coloca em um array e depois imprime esse array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    gerandoNumeroSorteio();
}

private static void gerandoNumeroSorteio() {
    int numeroTmp;
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
        numeroTmp = random.nextInt(60 + 1);

        if (!al.contains(numeroTmp)) {
            al.add(String.valueOf(numeroTmp));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Número repetido");
        }

        System.out.println("Nº numero sorteado = " + al.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um ArrayList de inteiro e preencher com os valores dos intervalos.
Depois pode usar a classe Random para sortear um indice do ArrayLit e remover em seguinda esse indice do ArrayList, assim os números não se repentirão.

```
public GeradorNumero(int min,int max) {
    r = new Random();
    this.numeros = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        this.numeros.add(i);
    }
}

public int gerarValor(){
    int posicao = r.nextInt(this.numeros.size());
    int valorGerado = this.numeros.get(posicao);
    this.numeros.remove(posicao);           
    return valorGerado;
}
```